# Recursive Mean in R vs. Rcpp

Tags: r, recursion, rcpp

I am trying to compute the mean of a variable using a simple, recursive implementation:

```
m <- 0 # initialize mean

for(irep in 0:999){

# new data point
new_data <- rnorm(1,2,1)

# recursive formula for sample mean
m = (irep/(irep+1)) * m + (1/(irep+1)) * new_data

}
```

Here, `m` will quickly converge to 2, which corresponds to the mean of the normal distribution where we generate new data points from. Implementing something similar in Rcpp:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double  rec_mean(int sample_size){

  double m = 0; //initialize mean

  for(int irep = 0; irep < sample_size; irep++){

      // new data
      double new_data = R::rnorm(2,1);

      // mean recursive update
      m = ((irep)/(irep+1)) * m + (1/(irep+1)) * new_data;

  }

  return m;

}
```

This code does not show the expected behavior. Instead, it returns the initial value. Can somebody enlighten me where my error in this translation from R to Rcpp is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this line:

```
m = ((irep)/(irep+1)) * m + (1/(irep+1)) * new_data;
```

You are dividing an `int` by another `int` twice. In C++, integer division returns another integer, discarding the remainder.

To get what you want, force the divisions to be done in floating point:

```
m = ((irep)/(irep+1.0)) * m + (1.0/(irep+1.0)) * new_data;
```